# Codeigniter resize and crop image

Tags: codeigniter, image-resizing, resize-crop, imagelibrary

I need to resize image to fit 64x64 thumbnail. What I'm doing? I set resize width and height to 64px. If I set  $config['maintain_ratio'] = false, image lose proportions. What I did: I set  $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE; and  $config['master_dim'] = 'width'; Now width is always 64px, but height is larger. I have somehow to crop image height to 64px from bottom. How can I achieve this? I tried to set up crop function, but I failed. Maybe there is another solution...
My resize function

```
private function resize($up_data) {
        $config['image_library']  = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image']   = $up_data['full_path'];   
        $config['new_image']      = './images/autoriaithumb/';
        $config['create_thumb']   = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = '_thumb';
        $config['width']          = 64;
        $config['height']         = 64;
        $config['quality']        = 100;
        $config['master_dim'] = 'width';

        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        $this->image_lib->resize();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this

define 'upload config' as $image_config and define your crop config....as $config

```
$this->load->library('upload', $image_config);
if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
  $this->load->library('image_lib',$config); 
  $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

Comment: I will try , but also I need to crop image from bottom. How can I achieve this?

Comment: see [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html)...check $this->image_lib->crop() write the code before or after resize code...

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore. I found the way how to solve it. :) Thanks for a help.

Comment: @anhelo If you figured out a way to solve it, you should answer your own question as an answer on here